# How to know if the 7th radio button is selected without knowing name or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a product page that dynamically creates item options. I would like to know if the 7th option is selected, but I wont know the "name" or "id" of the radio button because they are generated automatically.

```js
function teasamplecheck() {
 if(document.form1.radio1[7].checked == true) {
    alert("You have selected a sample");
}
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
        }
    }
}
});
```

```
<!--START: radio-format-->
<div class="radio-format" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<input type="radio" name="[oname]" id="radio-[value]" value="[value]" onClick="teasamplecheck();validateValues(document.add,1);updateprice();"  [selected]>
[feature]
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!--END: radio-format-->
```

So how to I look at this set of radio buttons and know that the 7th one is selected?

Comment: But you have a `value` to apply a `check` with...This is most safest way to go with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the jQuery [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) may be a way.

```
function teasamplecheck() {
    if( $(".radio-format input").eq(6).prop("checked") ) {
        alert("You have selected a sample");
    }
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

This is `.eq(6)` because the argument is zero-based.

So... This is the 7th input inside its parent `radio-format`...
If you have the whole `radio-format` div repeated many times... It would be :

```
function teasamplecheck() {
    if( $(".radio-format").eq(6).children("input").prop("checked") ) {
        alert("You have selected a sample");
    }
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
See question in comments

To trigger the alert ONLY if the click has occured on the 7th radio, you have to change the condition:

```
function teasamplecheck(obj) {
    if (( obj.value == $(".radio-format input").eq(6).val() ) && ( obj.checked )){
        alert("You have selected a sample");
    }
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

OR (if the whole `radio-format` div is repeated) :

```
function teasamplecheck(obj) {
    if (( obj.value == $(".radio-format").eq(6).children("input").val() ) && ( obj.checked )){
        alert("You have selected a sample");
    }
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

It compares the value of the `obj` passed by the `onclick` handler:

```
onClick="teasamplecheck(this); ...
```

Comment: This is great help... its performing as expected, except it runs the function all the time, not just when "teasamplecheck()" is called.

Comment: You call the function `onclick` of every radio... If it isn't what you want, you have to trigger the function on another condition. I suppose you want the alert ONLY onclick of the 7th... Hold on.

Comment: Do you use the 1st or the 2nd solution ?

Comment: Sorry... I think I know the issue! I put "teasamplecheck()" to fire everytime a radio button is checked, but thats not what I want. I can work out the rest. Thank you very much, you have been a lot of help.

Comment: Yes this is it... I will remove the last edit, since it isn't working lolll Just tested it.

Comment: You only have to add `this` in the generated HTML.